# Is it possible to do postprocessing on Android video output?

Tags: android

Is it possible to do some postprocessing on the video data that gets sent to the display driver in Android?

For context, what I would like to do would be to able to apply effects such as blurring, sharpening, increasing or decreasing constrast, on the entire screen output, regardless of what is running.

I would like to know if there is some way to grab the actual video data before it gets shown on screen, process it, and then send it to the screen, (a fairly low-level operation, which I don't believe is provided by the Android API - However, I am only a beginner and do not know how hard it would actually be) or if there is any way by which I would be able to simulate this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It may work by software in theory. However, performance may be the big issue. It can not be done in Jave app layer. Normally, it's done by HW(in Qualcomm platform, there is a specific device called MDP, which is mostly for video postprocessing).